# Query SQL Microsoft Access bug?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been working on an Access database with SQL. I was trying to perform the following query:

```
SELECT Produtos.produto,
      [aux].[total]/[Produtos].[existencias] AS [peso consumos nas existencias]
FROM (SELECT Produtos.produto, SUM(Consumos.quantidade) AS total 
      FROM Consumos, Produtos, Fornecedores 
      WHERE Consumos.codproduto=Produtos.produto 
        AND Produtos.codfornecedor=9 
      GROUP BY Produtos.produto 
      ORDER BY Produtos.produto)  AS aux 
INNER JOIN Produtos 
   ON aux.produto = Produtos.produto
WHERE (((aux.produto)=[Produtos].[produto]));
```

A closer look at the results showed me that the column [peso consumos nas existencias] was multiplied by 10. After trying to fix this, I noticed that I was not using the table Fornecedores although I was calling it after FROM keyword, so I removed it:

```
SELECT Produtos.produto,
       [aux].[total]/[Produtos].[existencias] AS [peso consumos nas existencias]
FROM (SELECT Produtos.produto, SUM(Consumos.quantidade) AS total 
      FROM Consumos, Produtos 
      WHERE Consumos.codproduto=Produtos.produto 
        AND Produtos.codfornecedor=9 
      GROUP BY Produtos.produto 
      ORDER BY Produtos.produto)  AS aux 
INNER JOIN Produtos 
   ON aux.produto = Produtos.produto
WHERE (((aux.produto)=[Produtos].[produto]));
```

After running, the results were right. Was this suppose to happen? if so, why?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it should happen. By including Fornecedores and not specifying the join criteria, you're effectively asking to outer join or get every row, thus returning multiple results. If you looked at just the inner query you'd probably see 10 times as many rows in your first sql as compared with your second sql.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Fornecedores` table probably has 10 records.

```
FROM Consumos, Produtos, Fornecedores 
WHERE Consumos.codproduto=Produtos.produto
```

was doing a **cartesian product** of the Consumos-Produtos join with those 10 records, so the SUM() used each number 10 times.

---

Note 1:
It is considered better style to use the explicit INNER JOIN syntax:

```
  FROM Consumos INNER JOIN Produtos 
       ON Consumos.codproduto=Produtos.produto 
  WHERE Produtos.codfornecedor=9
```

instead of `FROM Consumos, Produtos`

Note 2:
If you think you have found a bug in the Access (or any database) query engine, chances are almost 100% that the bug is in your query. ;-)